# Remove blank space from Pivot Item in Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

How to get rid of the blank space between a pivots item and the pivots borders?
I tried setting the margin and the padding to 0 but it does not help much. The reason I want to do this is the following - I figured that changing the template of the pivot to have a static ( not moving) header for three items is a bit hard and therefore I just put a StackPanel with three buttons above the pivot with three items, and I would manually select the pivot item in code behind when someone pushes the button. This approach is good enough for me, but has a certain flaw- a blank space between the items and the StackPannel , how can I remove it ?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
        <Button Click="Button_Click"/> 
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1"/> 
        <Button Click="Button_Click_2"/> 
    </StackPanel>
    <Pivot>
        <PivotItem>
            <local:someControl /> 
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
            <local:someControl />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
            <local:someControl /> 
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Please learn to include some code in your questions. It helps to avoid all the downvotes.

Comment: @JohnSaunders  your comment got me paranoid to the point when I started checking all the other questions I ever asked on this website- this is only the second one that does not include any code. Isn't describing the situation enough for this case ? It's not that much code either.. just a stack panel and a pivot.

Comment: Please show us the problem - don't make us guess. XAML is code too, for this purpose.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I added it, but perhaps a screenshot would be better ?

Comment: @JohnSaunders btw, do you actually know the answer and just want me to ask the question properly ?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I did want you to ask the question properly so that you can get an answer.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot clarifying what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `negative value` as margin to remove that blank space. Simply try

```
<Pivot Margin="0, -25, 0, 0">
```

Replace 25 with your desired value.

Comment: I actually did the same thing before you answered, but still thank you, it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `Pivot` margin to negative works, but there is a better way using styles.

```
<Pivot>
    <Pivot.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="PivotItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </Pivot.Resources>

    <PivotItem .../>
    <PivotItem .../>
</Pivot>
```